# jumbotron color manipulation with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a problem with javascript.I want to control the jumbotron color and set it every 3 seconds to a random one.The problem here is that i don't know how to manipulate CSS with JavaScript, as i am pretty new to javascript.
I saw some other solutions and some other threads but it did not work.(I don't know if i did anything wrong).
I have no js code written right now as i deleted everything that did not work.

```
.jumbotron { 
   background-color: #f14444 !important;
}
/*Without the !important rule it won't change color!*/
```

If you have any threads that you think i haven't checked i would be happy to check them but im confident enough to say that i've seen them already.

Thanks for your time anyways!

Comment: There's a lot of good info on that here: https://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript

Comment: [a fiddle, how to change the color of multiple, not connected nodes throughout the whole document at once using CSS vars](https://jsfiddle.net/xg7vzpfy/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the background color, simply select the element and the set the property:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('.jumbotron').style.backgroundColor = '#f14444';
}, 1000);
```

```css
.jumbotron {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron"></div>
```

Note that above will select the first found element with the given class, so if you need to target a specific element, consider giving it an `id` and select it as @Phil shows above.

Comment: You're weocome! @AlexPyrg

Answer (score 1):

Html elements in the DOM have a `style` property.

```
document.getElementById('something').style.backgroundColor = '#ccc'
```

Note that hyphenated properties like `background-color` in CSS are typically camel-case (backgroundColor) in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can achieve it with [keyframe animation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

Here is a [tutorial](http://miekd.com/articles/random-color-css3-animation/) how to get random color

```css
@-webkit-keyframes changeColors {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes changeColors {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes changeColors {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

.jumbotron {
  -webkit-animation: changeColors 3s infinite;
  -moz-animation: changeColors 3s infinite;
  -ms-animation: changeColors 3s infinite;
  background-color: #f14444;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  Some text here
</div>
```